# Linq to XML - way to write binary Data into XML

Tags: xml, linq

How to write binary data into XML using LINQ which is being read from registery.

Eg: Î®ì\ÎQÝÜ$Ñ.Ì6Å·xxµ0©ÐQfô:S9}:&......

Comment: XML isn't meant for binary data. Why are you trying to make it do strange things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to base64 encode the data and then set it as element text. [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Jon will give a start on you guidelines

Answer (score 2):

Use something like Base64 encoding to convert the binary into characters acceptable for XML.