# Binary data in XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-sql

How can I put file content in XML?

I am using Linq to SQL and my table has an binary type colums. I want to store table rows as XML file. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [base64-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) the binary data to transmit it as text.

See [Linq to XML (Base64 Encoded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009620/linq-to-xml-base64-encoded) and [Linq to XML - way to write binary Data into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809266/linq-to-xml-way-to-write-binary-data-into-xml).

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the binary data using Base16 or Base64 encoding. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64